# Render a view despite Exception

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra

I'm working with RestClient and because of the way my parameters are taken in, there's a chance that URLs aren't built correctly and a

```
RestClient::BadRequest
```

400 error is issued.  How can I render the view regardless?  I want to tell the user that their search didn't return any results.

I've consulted the documentation at https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#exceptions-see-wwww3orgprotocolsrfc2616rfc2616-sec10html but I still can't get it to work.

This is what I'm working with:

```
begin 
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: "[...]")
    @result  = JSON.parse(response)
rescue => e 
    @message = "Invalid search"
    @result = {}
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It should be easy. I think the view will be rendered regardless of the exception. Why not assign `@result` as empty in the rescue and check if the `@result` is empty at the view and print out the message if it's ?  Or are there any other factors affecting it ?

Comment: I tried doing that, it still give me the error page instead of the view. If it makes any difference, I'm using Huffington Post's pollster api.